# Prevent denormalization

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, denormalization

I was wondering how to prevent denormalization in this case:

```
Table Categories:

- id
- name

Table Category_types:

- id
- name

Association table: (category and category types are in a many-to-many relationship)

- id
- id_cat
- id_cat_type
```

I have a table `Request` where I have to store info about the `Category` of this `Request` and the `CategoryType`.
At the moment the schema is:

```
Request:

 - id
 - title
 - desc
 - id_cat
 - id_cat_type
```

By the way I think this is a bad idea, because there is a functional dependency (I guess?) between id_cat and id_cat_type.
I think I can solve this problem storing the id of the association table

```
Request:

 - id
 - title
 - desc
 - id_association_table
```

I know that splitting tables maybe would be the best option here, but I was wondering if there is some other approach to solve this kind of problems.

Thanks

Comment: If a category may have only one category type, you'd better just add a new column to `Categories` table referencing `Category_types.id`. If that's not the case, than what is the functional dependency you're talking about? Anyway, association table just for this purpose you've written about seems to be redundant.

Comment: Hi, ye sorry maybe I have to edit my question to explicitly explain that Category and CategoryType are in a many to many relationship. That's why I need the association table

Comment: Ok, this gets easier now. You have to understand all possible ways of using the association table. If you intend to use what you call "a functional dependency" only for requests, then let `Request` be the association table itself, otherwise use a separate table. Both approaches are fine, you just have to decide what's appropriate most.

Comment: This is not clear. You are not using terms sensibly. What does "prevent denormalization" mean? What do you think "denormalization" means? What do you think "normalization" means? Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS If you don't know whether there is a FD somewhere, find a textbook & relevant definitions, facts, algorithms & heuritstics & ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question re where you are 1st stuck. If you don't know how to do whatever it is you are trying to do, same thing. But it's not clear what your goal is given what or what your "problem" or question are.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov thanks for your help! I think that in my case the best approach could be using a separate table.  
That's because I want that every `Request` respect the association contraint defined between `Category` and `Category Type`.  
I don't want that every `Request` define his own association.

Comment: @philipxy Sorry that it's not clear, by the way I'll try to answer your question in these 500 char left. 1) With "prevent denormalization" I mean that I want to preserve my database in normal form, so if (I think) I'm not respecting 3rd normal form that would be a prob. I'm ready to "denormalize" my database only for read performance reason.
2) I edited my question after the comment to Pavel.
3) I read textbook etc, and I have not found an answer (or I didn't understood perfectly), that's why I'm here to discuss with someone more expert than me for an advice.

Comment: @philipxy (I failed to respect 500 chars) The problem here is that in theory a FD is when given same tuples in domain X, that yields to me the same tuples in domain Y (that's why they are dependent), but in my case I have something that I'm not sure is a FD! If I choose a Category it's not *obvious* which CategoryType it's connected to it, but it's obvious the subset of valid values :\ So there is a some kind of dependency....

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. But your comments are still not clear, you are still abusing terms, you haven't said what those words mean that you are using that I asked about or addressed the other issues in my comments. Putting words in scare quotes does not clarify the idiosyncratic meaning that you don't make clear by actually saying what you mean. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Again: Please don't ask us to write yet another textbook, ask a specific question about where you are 1st stuck following one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- Category CAT exists.
--
category {CAT}
      PK {CAT}
```

```
-- Category type TYP exists.
--
ctype {TYP}
   PK {TYP}
```

*For each category, that category may be of more than one category type. For each category type, more than one category may be of that category type.*

```
-- Category CAT is of type TYP.
--
category_ctype {CAT, TYP}
            PK {CAT, TYP}

FK1 {CAT} REFERENCES category {CAT}
FK2 {TYP} REFERENCES ctype    {TYP}
```

```
-- Request REQ is of category CAT, category type TYP.
--
request {REQ, CAT, TYP}
     PK {REQ}

FK {CAT, TYP} REFERENCES category_ctype {CAT, TYP}
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
FK = Foreign Key
```

Comment: Thanks, it was so obvious, but I didn't thought to that :D Well done